# MySQL: Slow GROUP BY with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have 2 tables to join.

Table 1: `helpdesk_tickets`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `helpdesk_tickets` (
  `ticket_idx` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bot_id` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_status` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_assignee_id` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chat_log_id_start` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chat_log_id_end` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chat_id` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_group` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_information` varchar(600) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_priority` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_idx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workspace_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workspace_idx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_idx`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `bot_id` (`bot_id`),
  KEY `comp_1` (`chat_log_id_start`,`chat_log_id_end`),
  KEY `workspace_id` (`workspace_id`),
  KEY `creation_date` (`creation_date`),
  KEY `idx_helpdesk_tickets_ticket_idx` (`ticket_idx`),
  KEY `chat_id` (`chat_id`),
  KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=604745 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 2: `chat_logs`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `chat_logs` (
  `chat_log_idx` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chat_log_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bot_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` mediumtext,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_from` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `chat_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `chat_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `chat_id` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `message_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_timestamp` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `broadcast_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`chat_log_idx`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `bot_id` (`bot_id`),
  KEY `message_from` (`message_from`),
  KEY `creation_date` (`creation_date`),
  KEY `chat_log_id` (`chat_log_id`),
  KEY `message_last_update` (`message_last_update`),
  KEY `message_id` (`message_id`),
  KEY `chat_type` (`chat_type`),
  KEY `chat_id` (`chat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14852380 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have around 80k rows in `helpdesk_tickets` and 16k rows in `chat_logs`.

Running this query

```sql
SELECT 
    chat_type, COUNT(ticket_id) AS total_tickets
FROM
    helpdesk_tickets AS ht
        INNER JOIN
    chat_logs AS cl ON cl.chat_id = ht.chat_id
GROUP BY chat_type;
```

takes very-very long time. It takes more than 10 minutes. It takes very long I never got to see the results because I always stopped the execution.

`EXPLAIN` gives me this

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows  | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ht    | NULL       | index | chat_id           | chat_id | 152     | NULL                   | 15870 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cl    | NULL       | ref   | chat_type,chat_id | chat_id | 152     | botmasterdb.ht.chat_id |  1838 |   100.00 | NULL                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Running this query alone without join is very fast, 0.04 seconds.

```sql
SELECT 
    chat_type
FROM
    chat_logs
GROUP BY chat_type;
```

The reason why I'm joining those 2 tables is to count how many tickets for each `chat_type`.

Comment: I'm sorry I should've added `COUNT` on the query. Edited.

Comment: Hm, it all looks good. I can't help wondering if there's something corrupt here.

Comment: I've created a DB-fiddle, and don't get the same query plan. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1hD4598H1uGizLC3vXfxp/0). By adding an extra key ,
  KEY `type_and_id` (`ticket_id`, `chat_id`) I do get use of that index.

Comment: Without data, the EXPLAIN isn't very meaningful

Answer (score 0):

Also...  You say `COUNT(ticket_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.  This forces the execution to check each `ticket_id` for being `NOT NULL`.  I suspect that is over-kill.  Do some or all of:

- Change the definition of `ticked_id` (and many other columns) to `NOT NULL`, _if appropriate
- Change to `COUNT(*)`
- Add the index already suggested: `INDEX(chat_id, ticket_id)`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why your have created so many indexes. My sugguestion is to analysis and reduce your indexes according to your business.

The following are how to optimized the query in this thread. Mysql version is `5.7.31` in my verification sandbox.

> 1. Add **conbination index** on `botika_chat_logs` table:

```
KEY idx_type_id (`chat_type`, `chat_id`)
```

> 2. Add **conbination index** on `botika_helpdesk_tickets` table:

```
KEY `index_chat_id_ticket_id` (`chat_id`, `ticket_id`)
```

> 3. Change query to:

```
SELECT
    chat_type, COUNT(ticket_id) AS total_tickets
FROM
    botika_chat_logs AS cl
        INNER JOIN
    botika_helpdesk_tickets AS ht ON cl.chat_id = ht.chat_id
GROUP BY chat_type;
```

The explain result is as following:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cl    | NULL       | index | idx_type_id             | idx_type_id             | 174     | NULL            |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ht    | NULL       | ref   | index_chat_id_ticket_id | index_chat_id_ticket_id | 152     | test.cl.chat_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

> The choice of a driving table made using many factors. Table sizes,
> cardinality of column values, and other things can affect the choice
> of a driving table (eg: HINTS). More details about how to choose
> driving table, please refer to [this doc](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:192812348072)

However, when I test the query above using different join order, the execution plan result is defferent. I think it may be caused by no data in my own sandbox.
The execution plan is as following. That why I still give you that query in Step 3.

```
mysql> explain SELECT
    ->     chat_type, COUNT(ticket_id) AS total_tickets
    -> FROM
    ->     botika_helpdesk_tickets AS ht
    ->         INNER JOIN
    ->     botika_chat_logs AS cl ON cl.chat_id = ht.chat_id
    -> GROUP BY chat_type;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    24
Current database: test

+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                 | key     | key_len | ref             | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ht    | NULL       | ALL  | chat_id                       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            |    1 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cl    | NULL       | ref  | chat_type,chat_id,idx_id_type | chat_id | 152     | test.ht.chat_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

**The `table sizes`, `cardinality of column values` and indexed in your tables must be different with that on my sandbox. Be sure to check execution plan on your sandbox.**

---

Why the query will be faster, after adding those indexes:

1. `botika_chat_logs` have less records than `botika_helpdesk_tickets`. The performance will be better if `botika_chat_logs` is the driving table.
2. Index `index_chat_id_ticket_id` is a `covering` index, which contains ticket_id and chat_id. When counting ticket_id, mysql will not need to return primary index.
3. New created index **`idx_type_id`** is a `covering` index, which will let query have better performance.
4. Group by chat_type will benifit from New created index **`idx_type_id`** too.

Comment: a x b is the same as b x a, and the execution plan will likewise be identical.

Comment: @Strawberry, I guess you mean no matter botika_chat_logs join to botika_helpdesk_tickets, or botika_helpdesk_tickets join to botika_chat_logs, the optimizer in mysql will optimize the executing plan and the execution plan should be the same. I agree with you at that point. However, in my sandbox, the execution plan is different when put botika_helpdesk_tickets in left of join, and I think that may be caused by no data in those table created in my sandbox. I will update my anwser to make it more clear

Comment: Were we to use a LEFT JOIN then certainly the execution plans would be different, and you might then have a point, but we're not, so you don't.